# Any support for Ryzen 2200g iGPU?

Tags: display, release-juno, graphic-drivers, graphics

I wanted to try the OS so I downloaded the latest version. But when it boots up, I noticed that my screen is split in two and the bottom half was stretched. Is there a fix for this?

I am using AMD Ryzen 2200g (iGPU). I did tried using it on a pc with AMD R7 gpu and it worked fine.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to install the latest MESA drivers, you could add the official repositories

1º `sudo apt update`

2º `sudo apt install software-properties-common`

3º `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates`

4º `sudo apt update`

5º `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

They work very well in my case, even in games. if u want privative drivers i have a video for install privative drivers: https://youtu.be/_zDLT9wQHmU

source:

https://translate.google.cl/translate?hl=es-419&sl=es&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muylinux.com%2F2017%2F03%2F28%2Fubuntu-ppa-mesa%2F

https://www.muylinux.com/2017/03/28/ubuntu-ppa-mesa/