# Install AMD A10-8700P Radeon R6 driver

Tags: graphic-drivers, drivers, amd

How to install driver for AMD A10-8700P Radeon R6 graphic card?

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Carrizo
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: c5
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
   resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f0800000-f0ffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: install Mesa drivers see this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/17639/any-support-for-ryzen-2200g-igpu/17644#17644

Comment: This [article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) covers installing latest AMD driver in ubuntu 18.04. If you are using eOS Juno than you can follow this as its based on 18.04 of Ubuntu also known as Bionic Beaver.